# Discord Bot that dms someone when a channel is created is not working

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
from discord.ext import commands
import discord
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

@bot.event
async def on_guild_channel_create(channel):
 message =  "This Message is sent via DM"
 user = bot.get_user("My_Discord_ID")
 await user.send(message)


bot.run("TOKEN")
```

I ran the code but nothing happened. I am not sure whats going on.

Answer (score 1):

To create a private message with a user, you must use the [`User.create_dm()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.User.create_dm) method to obtain a channel. Once you have fetched that channel, you can send content to the user.

```py
import discord

@bot.event
async def on_guild_channel_create(channel):
    user = bot.get_user("My_Discord_ID")
    channel = await user.create_dm()

    try: await channel.send("This Message is sent via DM")
    except discord.HTTPException: print("User has DMs disabled")
```